# Javascript in android webview with js libraries

Tags: javascript, android

How can i use this js code in android

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var testdiv = document.querySelectorAll("table.troisbords:nth-child(6) table.troisbords div.box_login:nth-child(1) table:nth-child(1) tbody:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2) > img:nth-child(1)");

    html2canvas($("#testdiv"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.open(myImage);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

i did this, but i'm getting many errors

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     view.loadUrl("javascript: ( <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
            var testdiv = document.querySelectorAll("table.troisbords:nth-child(6) table.troisbords div.box_login:nth-child(1) table:nth-child(1) tbody:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2) > img:nth-child(1)");

            html2canvas($("#testdiv"), {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
                var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                window.open(myImage);
            }
    });
        });
</script>
    })();");
}
```

how can i integrate it into the `view.loadUrl("javascript:` correctly ?

**Edit after Lakshmi Sankar and lvl4fi4 answer**

i need to use html2canvas library to get a screenshot of an element **in a website loaded** in a webview

this is the website and the element

https://www4.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud?ident=cin

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just put that code in a html file and save that file in android assets folder. [image: asset folder]

like the sample.html file in the picture and load that html in android like this

```
    String htmlFilename = "sample.html";
    AssetManager mgr = getBaseContext().getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream in = mgr.open(htmlFilename, AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER);
        String htmlContentInStringFormat = StreamToString(in);
        in.close();
        htmlWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlContentInStringFormat, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edited:

1) Enable the JavaScript

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

2) Make your external script look like this

```
javascript: (function() {

function loadDynamicJS(file, parent) {
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
    jsElm.src = file;
    parent.appendChild(jsElm);
}

loadDynamicJS('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js', document.head);
loadDynamicJS('http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js', document.head);

var testdiv = document.querySelectorAll("table.troisbords:nth-child(6) table.troisbords div.box_login:nth-child(1) table:nth-child(1) tbody:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2) > img:nth-child(1)");

html2canvas($("#testdiv"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        window.open(myImage);
    }
});})();
```

3) Add the above script here

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    webView.loadUrl("YOUR SCRIPT HERE");
}});
```

if youre enabling webview js you should be careful only do it ifs necessary

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but i'm wondering, is that will use a html page in a webview instead of the website ? so the javascript will run in the html page , please check my edited question

Answer (score 0):

put your script in a html file and put them in `asset` folder in project.

**test.html**

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #2C7CC3;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    function callFromActivity(){
        html2canvas($("#testdiv"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                window.android.onData(myImage);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="testdiv">
    <input type="text"></input>
    <button onclick="callFromActivity();">Click me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

create a utility class for reading `test.html` from `asset`.

**ReadAsset.java**

```
    public class ReadAsset {
    public static String read(String filePath, Context context) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(filePath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(str);
        }
        br.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

in your layout create a `WebView`.
**WebView** :

```
 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_start">

</WebView>
```

in your activity create `interface` to get call back from javascript

**interface in activity**

```
  @JavascriptInterface
public void onData(String value) {
    android.util.Log.d("WebView", value);
    String html = "<html><body><img src=\"" + value + "\"/></body></html>";
    this.runOnUiThread(() ->
            webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8"));
}
```

and finally setup your `webview` and call `callFromActivity()` from html buttom or from android buttom

**activity codes**

```
 WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    String html = "";
    try {
        html = ReadAsset.read("test.html", this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            android.util.Log.d("WebView", consoleMessage.message());
            return true;
        }
    });
    //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");

    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");


    findViewById(R.id.btn_start).setOnClickListener(v -> start());
}

void start() {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript("callFromActivity();", null);
    } else {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity();");
    }
}
```

what will happen is you take a screenshot and load it again in `webview` but you will have the `base64` data in activity so you can do whatever you want with it or you can use `javascript` and use image there.

Comment: Appreciate your reply, please correct me if i'm wrong, this will load a html page then use the javascript in it right?
i edited my question, please check, 
what i'm trying to do is take a screenshot of a captcha in a website using javascript, so i need to use html2canvas library in order to do that

Comment: That’s exactly what it will do .

Comment: you mean it will take screenshot from the url i loaded in webview or from html file ?

Comment: Yes , but you have to iframe if you intend to get captcha from another url . You will have the library in a page that has a iframe which loads captcha from another url and just get the screenshot through html elements

Comment: i can use the link only once, because the captcha will reload

Comment: if you can edit your code to just open url instead of html local page

Comment: Can i use js file and call the function in it to android ?

Comment: You can’t access iframe from other domain . If the only thing you need is the captcha code image then you may consider to use webview only to load that page and get the image through webview methods

Comment: that's the first thing i tried; there's not a way to do that
i'm know trying css js and jquery to zoom in on the captcha and resize the webview
all questions similaire to me about how to get captcha without refreshing the link have no answers

Comment: I will find a way soon

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround to do that,

i deleted all css files in the website, then i replaced an image in the top left corner with captcha image

All that in onPageFinished using javascript

```
  @Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript: (function(){        var selector = '#top1 > p > img'; document.head.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement('style'), { innerText: '*{visibility:hidden}' + selector + '{visibility:visible}' }));\n" +
            "document.body.style.marginLeft=\"0px\";\n" +
            "document.body.style.marginTop=\"0px\";\n" +
            "$(\"body > link:nth-child(1)\").removeAttr(\"href\");\n" +
            "$(\"body > link:nth-child(4)\").removeAttr(\"href\");\n" +
            "$(\"head > link:nth-child(18)\").removeAttr(\"href\");\n" +
            "document.querySelector(\"#top1 > p > img\").src=\"/ORegMx/capito.png\";\n})();");
}
```